# how to add custom dimensions in existing icCube schema file

Tags: iccube

I need to add custom dimensions in existing icCube schema file. not sure how to do that using REST API.
Please give me example code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API in icCube to modify parts of an existing schema.

You can download an existing schema using the current [Rest API](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/api/index.php). Change the schema definition using a template or a search/replace mechanism and load it again into icCube.